# How to refer to a file for fs.readfile

Tags: node.js, path, readfile, fs

I have a node.js application that uses a static csv file that i build some values from. My project structure is as follows:

```
/-- <app>
/-- -- sampledata.csv
/-- -- <server>
/-- -- -- server.js
```

the way i refer to this file through server.js is:

```
path.join(__dirname, "..", "sampledata.csv")
```

when i try reading the file:

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "sampledata.csv"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
    //code
}
```

I get the error

```
Cannot destructure property `data` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Can anyone tell me how to point to the right location in the directory as i think it's using the path as the string name?

Comment: Sorry, i had the wrong error on the screen.

Comment: try this : 

fs.readFile(__dirname + '../sampledata.csv',"utf8", (err, data) => {
    //code
}

Comment: Hmm... Please check your actual code. The error comes from a destructuring operation, meaning that you'll have something like ({err, data}) in your code, at least that what it looks like.